# Calling a function within a for loop - JavaScirpt

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

Hi I am trying to call a function within a for loop but It isn't working...This is how my code currently looks like:

```
bot.on('message', data => {
    if (data.type !== 'message' || data.subtype === 'bot_message') {
        return;
    }
    findClassroomMention(data,text);
});

var classrooms = 
    {
        L108: ["lokaal 108","L108","108"],
        L208: ["lokaal 208","L208","208"]
    };

function findClassroomMention(message) {    
    var found = false   
    for(var ClassroomId in classrooms) {
        for(var term of classrooms[ClassroomId]) {
            if(message.includes(term)) {
                found = ClassroomId;
                notifyProblemSolver();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (found) notifyProblemSolver(); break;
    }
    return found
};

function notifyProblemSolver(ClassroomId) {
    const params = {
        icon_emoji: ':smiley:'
    }
    bot.postMessageToChannel('caris','We have a problem in' + ClassroomId, params);
};
```

I want the function notifyProblemSolver() to be called in the for loop...But if I run the code it isn't working. Any tips? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger?

Comment: I'd encourage you to to take @PowellYe's advice and try the `debugger;` statement in javascript (with the console open). This kind of issue is the perfect use case for the `debugger;`. Now is a good time to learn it since you are having a problem it can easily fix.

Comment: If I debug it says the following: inspect-brk=41089 index.js

Comment: @Martijn_- For a very brief introduction to the `debugger;` have a look at https://underscore-patterns.herokuapp.com/learningMaterial/code/vanilla/zz_debugger.html

Answer (score 0):

I think `if (found) notifyProblemSolver; break;` is the issue. That `break` will be called regardless of `if (found)` so `for(var ClassroomId in classrooms) {` will only run once.

I think you meant

`if (found) {
    notifyProblemSolver();
    break;
}`

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some unnecessary semicolons at the end of functions. Also the part:

```
if (found) notifyProblemSolver; break;
```

Should be replaced with:

```
if (found) notifyProblemSolver(); break;
```

Because you are calling a function here, instead it was an expression.

Let me know if this works.

Full code modification here:
https://jsfiddle.net/terza_terza/ms9xLrzu/3/